# How do I stop cannons from attacking enemy units?

Tags: bos-wars

I am playing a game against the AI, and I have just finished building a cannon. If the cannon detects enemy units in its range, it will attack the enemy units. This is usually the desired behavior.

However, suppose the territory I control is small. Suppose I have now obtained an unofficial ceasefire (i.e. enemies are not attacking), but lots of enemy units are within firing range of the cannon. I do not want to provoke a retaliation from the enemy by attacking enemy units using the cannon.

Is there a way to disable a cannon so as not to provoke retaliation from enemy units?